# getting error message Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values. in FromSqlRaw

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying get data list from database using FromSqlRaw

```
var ProjectLocationCode= new SqlParameter("@ProjectCode", ProjectCode);
ProjectLocationCode.Value = (object)ProjectCode ?? DBNull.Value;

var ProjectLocationList =  db.ProjectLocationList.FromSqlRaw("EXEC [BI].GetProjectLocation @ProjectCode", ProjectLocationCode).AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

this is getting me error message "Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values." in the database we have NULL value. is there are way get empty text for each row ?

Comment: Change the DML inside the GetProjectLocation  (Stored Procedure) to return empty instead of null

Comment: Looks like the stored proc is returning some null data and that is being assigned to some non null property. That's why you're getting this error. What data do you get when you run the stored proc directly against database with the same parameter value?

Comment: yap i will change the SP with ISNULL()